# Can I have an LSP pay for the training cost in my Custom Translator workspace?

Tags: microsoft-translator

We are having a discussion with our LSP (they have their own subscription key) that they will perform the trainings for us in our Custom Translator workspace and also pay for the training cost that will be incurred. But according to the current set up the fee would automatically be charged to our subscription as the training material would be uploaded to our workspace. Would it be possible that Microsoft could allow this in the settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The LSP would need to train in their own workspace in order to assume the cost. You can consume the LSP-trained system from your own Azure account, then you would bear the consumption cost.
If you want the LSP continue using your workspace, you'd have to have the LSP subtract the training cost from the LSP's charges to you.

Comment: If I have the LSP train the engines, will they be able to transfer the ownership of the engines to my account? Thanks

Comment: You can use a trained engine regardless of ownership. The ownership is really associated with the project, including all its training data and project metadata. The owner can share the workspace with you, so you can see all of that, and operate the project, but it won't automatically move into your own workspace.